# Resolving Diamond Inheritance within Python Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Consider the following python code:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, serial_number):
        self.name = name
        self.serial_number = serial_number


class ChildA(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, serial_number):
        self.name = name
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        super(ChildA, self).__init__(name = self.name, serial_number = self.serial_number)

    def speak(self):
        print("I am from Child A")


class ChildB(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, serial_number):
        self.name = name
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        super(ChildB, self).__init__(name = self.name, serial_number = self.serial_number)

    def speak(self):
        print("I am from Child B")


class GrandChild(ChildA, ChildB):
    def __init__(self, a_name, b_name, a_serial_number, b_serial_number):
        self.a_name = a_name
        self.b_name = b_name
        self.a_serial_number = a_serial_number
        self.b_serial_number = b_serial_number
        super(GrandChild, self).__init_( something )
```

When running the `super` function in GrandChild, what is the proper way to format the `__init__` arguments so that ChildA and ChildB both get the correct arguments?

Also how do you access the two different versions of the `speak` method (ChildA's version and ChildB's version) from within the GrandChild class?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a valid use-case for multiple-inheritance. Why not use composition instead?

Comment: I think "Inheritance problems due to incest" would be a more appropriate title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

so, when you call super from the grandchild, `ChildA`'s `__init__` method will be called because super follows the `__mro__` property (parents left to right then grandparents left-to-right, then great grandparents, ...)

Since `ChildA`'s **init** also calls super, then all the super calls will be chained, calling child b's `__init__` and eventually the parent init.

For that to work, your interface generally needs to be consistent. That is positional arguments need to mean the same things, and be in the order.

In situations where that's not the case, keyword arguments may work better.

```
class Parent:    
    def __init__(self, name, serial, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.serial = serial

class ChildA(Parent):    
    def __init__(self, a_name, a_serial, **kwargs):
        self.a_name = a_name
        self.a_serial = a_serial
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class ChildB(Parent):    
    def __init__(self, b_name, b_serial, **kwargs):
        self.b_name = b_name
        self.b_serial = b_serial
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class GrandChild(ChildA, ChildB):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name = "blah", a_name = "a blah", b_name = "b blah", a_serial = 99, b_serial = 99, serial = 30)
```

Also note that in your code `name` and `serial` are reused as instance properties between all the classes and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: `ChildA` and `ChildB` needing to be aware of each other so that their arguments don't collide seems like code smell to me

Answer (score 4):

In python, you [can](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) explicitly call a particular method on (one of) your parent class(es):

```
ChildA.__init__(self, a_name, a_serial)
ChildB.__init__(self, b_name, b_serial)
```

Note that you need to put the `self` in explicitly when calling this way.

You can also – as you did – use the `super()` way, which will call the "first" parent. The exact order is dynamic, but by default it will do left-to-right, depth-first, pre-order [scans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) of your inheritance hierarchy. Hence, your `super()` call will only call `__init__` on `ChildA`.

Comment: When I call super in the GrandChild class it does call both ChildA and ChildB's __init__ function. The way I verified this was by putting print statements in both __init__ funcitons and both were printed out.

Comment: I don't think the order is ltr depth-first, because that would call the grand parent between the first child and the second child and that's not what happens.  Each super call will only call one new method, but it chains when each called method also calls super.

Comment: I clarified the scanning order. The order is L->R, depth first (it will try the grandparent before trying the 2nd parent), but it will try the parent before the grantparent (pre-order scanning).

Answer (score 0):

The Diamond problem doesn’t exist in Python because it gives preference to the class that gets inherited first.

Two important rules:

1. We go from Left to Right.
2. We goto the parent when all the children are considered.

   ```
   class Parent:    
       def __init__(self, name, serial):
           self.name = name
           self.serial = serial

       def printName(self):
           print("Inside P");

   class ChildA(Parent):    
       def __init__(self, a_name, a_serial):
           self.a_name = a_name
           self.a_serial = a_serial

       def printName(self):
           print("Inside A");

   class ChildB(Parent):    
       def __init__(self, b_name, b_serial):
           self.b_name = b_name
           self.b_serial = b_serial

       def printName(self):
           print("Inside B");


   class GrandChild(ChildA, ChildB):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__(name = "blah", a_name = "a blah", b_name = "b blah", a_serial = 99, b_serial = 99, serial = 30)

   obj = GrandChild();
   obj.printName();
   ```

   Output is **Inside A**

   In the above example, **GrandChild(ChildA, ChildB)** denotes that class GrandChild inherited class ChildA first, followed by class ChildB.

   If you switch places of an inherited child in GC class then:

   ```
   class GrandChild(ChildB, ChildA):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__(name = "blah", a_name = "a blah", b_name = "b blah", a_serial = 99, b_serial = 99, serial = 30)

   obj = GrandChild();
   obj.printName();
   ```

   Output is **Inside B**