# How do I access methods from parent classes with super in diamond inheritance in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make diamond inheritance and call the parent methods inside the child class using `super`. I get unexpected result:

```
class Base:
    def func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class A(Base):
    def func(self):
        print("A")


class B(Base):
    def func(self):
        print("B")


class C(A, B):
    def func(self):
        super(A, self).func()
        super(B, self).func()


c = C()
c.func()
```

I assumed to have `A` and `B` as the result but I get:

```
B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    c.func()
  File "main.py", line 19, in func
    super(B, self).func()
  File "main.py", line 3, in func
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

How do I fix my code? I use Python 3.8.

I've seen I can use an expression like `A.func(self)` but it does not seem to be pretty and it makes me confused in what `super` is for then.

Comment: Given that diamond inheritance is often referred to as the Deadly Diamond of Death, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving Diamond Inheritance within Python Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199975/resolving-diamond-inheritance-within-python-classes)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: you need to take in to account the *Method Resolution Order*.

```
(<class '__main__.C'>,
 <class '__main__.A'>,
 <class '__main__.B'>,
 <class '__main__.Base'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

It searches through class A, going to B, before finally settling for functions in Base.  So you're only gonna be able to effectively use those lower functions if you don't overwrite their names with ones higher in the pecking order.

https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pprint
pp = pprint .PrettyPrinter()

class Base:
    def func( self ):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class A( Base ):
    def funca( self ):
        print( 'A' )


class B( Base ):
    def funcb( self ):
        print( 'B')


class C( A, B ):
    def func( self ):
        super() .funca()
        super() .funcb()
        super() .func()

pp .pprint( C .__mro__ )  ##  Method Resolution Order

c = C()
c .func()
```