# Diamond problem with constructor - Python

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I have a problem with the constructor of the WorkingStudent class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__ (self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, Id, grades):
        super().__init__(firstName, lastName)
        self.Id = Id
        self.grades = grades

class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, title, salary):
        super().__init__(firstName, lastName)
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary

class WorkingStudent(Student, Worker):
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, Id, grades, title, salary):
        Student.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, Id, grades)
        Worker.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, title, salary)


ws = Worker("Tony", "Soprano", 123, "F")
ws.title="worker"
ws.salary=2400
```

When I try to create a class object this way:

```
ws = Worker("Tony", "Soprano", 123, "F", "worker", 2400)
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

How should I create a constructor of WorkingStudent class?

Comment: You should read up on "cooperative inheritance" - you could use `super` in `WorkingStudent` too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to create a "working student" by initialising a "worker" class instance?

The worker class takes 5 arguments (including the `self` argument), whereas the workingstudent class takes 7. You're now giving `self` + 6 arguments to the Worker class...

Try changing

```
ws = Worker("Tony", "Soprano", 123, "F", "worker", 2400)
```

to

```
ws = WorkingStudent("Tony", "Soprano", 123, "F", "worker", 2400)
```

**==EDIT==**

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200507/7549479

The class signatures should be consistent, so you can use `**kwargs` to let every class accept (ignored) keyword arguments.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, but it doen't work:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ws = WorkingStudent("Tony", "Soprano", 123, "F", "worker", 2400)
    Student.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, Id, grades)_
    super().__init__(firstName, lastName)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'title' and 'salary'

Comment: @LadySylwia think about the _method resolution order_; `super` in `Student` from a `WorkingStudent` is `Worker`.

Comment: I thought```super``` in ```Student``` from ```WorkingStudent``` is ```Person```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but it works:

```
class Person:
    def __init__ (self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, Id, grades, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Id = Id
        self.grades = grades

class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self, title, salary, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.salary = salary

class WorkingStudent(Student, Worker):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

ws = WorkingStudent(123, "F", "title", 2400, "Tony", "Soprano")

ws2 = WorkingStudent(firstName="Tony", lastName="Soprano", Id="123", title="worker", salary=2400, grades="F")
```

In `ws` I need to give the arguments in this order! -> It works

In `ws2` printing `firstName` and `lastName` gives 'firstName' and 'lastName' not  'Tony' and 'Soprano'